# How can I extract Moran's I from buffered pixels withins raster

Tags: raster, r, extract, moran-index

I have a raster with NDVI and I have a dataframe with coordinates I want to extract stats from at a 125m radius.

```
extract(NDVI,coordinates,method='simple',buffer=125,fun=mean)
```

this works for most of my needs, but I also need a Moran's I for each coordinate buffer.

```
extract(NDVI,coordinates,method='simple',buffer=125,fun=Moran)
```

I get the following error message, presumably because it needs a raster to work on which the data no longer is:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘cellStats’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

Is there a way to do this? I have attempted to recreate a new raster from only the pixels I want using the `rasterfromcells` function, but found it to be a dead end.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a bit nonsensical both from a procedural and statistical standpoint. Alternatively, you can calculate the local Moran's-I (there is a raster function to do this) on the NDVI and then simply extract the raster values to your points. Do not take the mean of values around the points as, the resulting moment will be invalid and a distance/neighbor is already built into the statistic.

Comment: thank you. can you elaborate on why you think it's nonsensical? I was wanting to use Morans to quantify degree of vegetation clustering within these points (they're desert rivers so very sparse, narrow canopy). Do you mean it's pointless to calculate the different components of Moran's and then Moran's itself?

Comment: Because the I statistic is predicted on the observed global mean. You are functionally taking samples of the random field and deriving the I without considering the process they are being drawn from. The samples are not comparable to each other or the process they were drawn from. They do not integrate globally, which is why there is a local derivation of the statistic (LISA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `crop` (and possibly "mask") to return the raster within a polygon formed by making a circle of 125m radius centred on each of your sample points and then run Moran on that.

Repeat for each sampling point.

(Make a circle of 125m radius by making a point at the location and using a 125m buffer, or via trigonometry, using sp or sf package functions)

Comment: thanks for your comment. this was basically how I carried this out in QGIS, but I'm not sure how I could turn it into a function in R (there's a lot of sampling points). in this scenario i'd need to convert each of my points in my df into individual circular polygons right? can you specify which sp/sf command you mean?

Comment: `st_buffer` for `sf` objects (which you might have to convert to `sp` to use with the raster package) or `gBuffer` from the `rgeos` package for `sp` objects.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. as you said i was eventually able to do it by applying a buffer upon changing the points to an sf object, then masked the intervals after changing them again to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame